# Electron Pakaging issue for Windows in Mac Os 10.11.6

Tags: windows, macos, electron-builder

I am using mac OS 10.11.6. My elecron build for mac OS is successful but for Windows it is giving the following error

***`⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 1 errorOut=wine: failed to initialize: dlopen(/tmp/wine-stage/wine/usr/lib/wine/ntdll.dll.so, 258): image not found`***

I am using     "electron-builder": "22.3.2" in package.json

I have seen various post on this issue but no proper solutions. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Only Option for me to make it work is to upgrade MacOs(OSX EI Captain) to macOS Mojave( 10.14.6).

Somewhere I read some packaging tools have issues with macOS catalina , So I did not opt for it for upgrade and considered Mojave.

Note: The upgrade experience was not that smooth. 
a) Upgrade Process itself took more than 8hrs and I had to leave the laptop for overnight after waiting for 3hrs. But luckily , when I checked in the morning , the laptop was booted up to login screen
b) When I tried to login, it stuck for hrs there, but I realised after googling it is a common issue and many people faced it. Then I had to follow safe mode booting clearing of NVM etc process . But finally it is thru
c) Finally  npm install of my app which was working before , broke and the solution was to do

```
xcode-select --install
```

d) Subsequently the windows build was done without any issue and app is working fine now.

So in short, unless you have at least one day to keep aside , do not attempt the OS upgrade.